# How to make HTTP requests from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, api, typescript, async-await

How to make API calls from typescript, can "async-await" be used with it?

I am converting React to TypeScript

Using Axios right now to making HTTP Requests

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript. You should just be able to import whatever HTTP library you want.

Comment: do i need typings to use any js lib in typescript i want to use react-notification in typescript but cant make it work

Comment: You can't make what work? If you want help you'll need to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: okay for http request i am using axios and it works fine in typescript as well

but i need to know, is typings required to make any js library work in typescript?

    "import { NotificationContainer, NotificationManager } from 'react-notifications';"

the above says react-notification not found and i cant find typings for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41929586/5027628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) can be used to make http requests

Axios has typings available, so can be easily used with Typescript

```
npm install axios

typings install dt~axios --global
```