# Is it necessary to have typing/definiton files for every JS library you use in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Is it necessary to have typing for every JS library you use in typescript?
if not, then how to get rid of errors and make use of a library which doesn't have  available definition files

```
import { NotificationContainer, NotificationManager } from 'react-notifications';
```

can't find typings for react-notifications

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3019; https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6615. Looks like `declare module` will do the trick.

Comment: It is not mandatory to have typings for each library you use but it would be extremely convenient especially if you are using an IDE or text editor that supports code suggestions (i.e. Visual Studio Code). This lessens time looking at documentation or source code.

Comment: @JD import ReactSummernote from 'react-summernote'; this gives error as react-summernote typings are not available, how do you get rid of these errors

Comment: You can create a typing containing only this code: `declare module "react-summernote" {}`

Comment: @JDHrnnts on doing that module not found is gone but i am getting an error- "TS2604 JSX element type 'ReactSummernote' does not have any construct or call signatures"
....
import * as ReactSummernote from 'react-summernote';

Comment: If you want to avoid any errors in the future when using TypeScript, make sure that you define a proper typings file (extension: .d.ts) in your app. Usually, modules such as React, Redux, validator, etc. has publicly available typings definition (one source is DefinitelyTyped). On the other hand, if you have self-crafted modules, it is your responsibility to create typescript definitions for them. Please take a look at this [guide](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/creating.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary. For your example, you create a file `react-notifications.d.ts` (you can call it anything you like as long as the extension is `.d.ts` but it makes sense to name it consistently):

```
declare module "react-notifications" {

    const NotificationContainer: any;
    const NotificationManager: any;
}
```

That's a near-minimal starting point. But you could go a little further and improve on those `any` declarations. They are a temporary cop-out.

Comment: i made definition dile for react-summernote like this..
on doing that module not found is gone but i am getting an error- "TS2604 JSX element type 'ReactSummernote' does not have any construct or call signatures" .... did "import * as ReactSummernote from 'react-summernote';"

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Daniel Earwicker answer, as long as you are in a commonJS environment (and I guess you are using webpack) is to simply `require` the library using node `require`

```
const rn = require('react-notifications')
```

then use `rn.NotificationContainer` directly or `import NotificationContainer = rn.NotificationContainer`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547859/typescript-how-to-write-definition-file-for-react-jsx